# Help in drawing a graph (graph theory)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Can anyone help me to write the code to have the same graph as in the image below?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[column sep=2em, row sep=10ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
        \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]V1}, fill=green] (V1) {}; & & & & & \node[mypoint, label={above:$V_{2}$}] (V2) {};\\


        \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-4pt]V5}] (V5) {}; & & & & &  
        \node[mypoint, label={below left:V4}] (V4) {}; & & & & &  
        \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=2pt]V3}] (V3) {};\\
    };
    \draw (V1) -- (V2);
    \draw (V5) -- (V1);
    \draw (V5) -- (V4);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please can you complete your code with a minimal preamble and `document` environment? Right now, nobody but you knows how your custom style is defined, for example, so nobody can compile what you have.

Comment: Note that you don't need to name the nodes. You can use `M-1-1` etc. to refer to them, as you've named the matrix already.

Comment: thank you, but i dont understand what do you mean

Comment: @cfr I think that works only if the `matrix` is a `matrix of nodes`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2.,0.)-- (2.,0.);
\draw(-2.,-1.) circle (1.cm);
\draw (-2.,4.)-- (-2.,0.);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,4.)}] (0.,4.) ellipse (2.1cm and 0.5cm);
\draw (0.2,5.2) node[anchor=north west] {$e_1$};
\draw (0.2,3.4) node[anchor=north west] {$e_2$};
\draw (2.1,4.3) node[anchor=north west] {$v_4$};
\draw (-2.7,4.4) node[anchor=north west] {$v_3$};
\draw (-2.7,2.3) node[anchor=north west] {$e_3$};
\draw (2.2,0.4) node[anchor=north west] {$v_1$};
\draw (-2.8,0.4) node[anchor=north west] {$v_2$};
\draw (-2.8,-2.0) node[anchor=north west] {$e_4$};
\draw (0.1,-0.1) node[anchor=north west] {$e_5$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (-2.,0.) circle (3.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (2.,0.) circle (3.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-2.,4.) circle (3.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (2.,4.) circle (3.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Let me try to explain a bit the code.

```
\matrix[<options>] (<name>) {<code>};
```

produces a `matrix` (similar to a `tabular`) with some `<options>`, called `<name>`, whose rows are specified in `<code>`. I think it could be a good exercise for you to search for the meaning of the various options I used in [the TikZ & PGF Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\node[<options>] (<name>) {<text>};
```

produces a point called `<name>`, with the characteristic specified by `<options>` and some `<text>` inside. Since your nodes don't have text inside but outside I used the option `label={[<label-options>]<label-text>}`, which put a label, with a text `<label-text>`, near the node (the position of the label is specified by the `<label-options>`). Note that, since all your nodes are `circle, fill=black`, I've also created a `style` called `mypoint` to avoid writing the common options every time.

```
\draw (<node-start>) to [<options>] node[<label-position>]{<label-text>} (<node-end>);
```

draws a line from `<node-start>` to `<node-end>`, with some `<options>`, with a `<label-text>` positioned at `<label-position>`.

```
\draw (<node>) arc (<start-angle>:<stop-angle>:<radius>) node[<label-position>] {<label-text>};
```

draws an arc around `<node>` which begins at `<start-angle>` and ends at `<stop-angle>`, with a radius `<radius>` and a `<label-text>` positioned at `<label-position>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{%
    mypoint/.style={circle, fill=black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=6em, row sep=10ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt] (M) {%
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-6pt,yshift=-3pt]V3}] (V3) {}; & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]V4}] (V4) {}; \\
    \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=2pt,yshift=4pt]V2}] (V2) {}; & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]V1}] (V1) {}; \\
};
\draw (V3) to [bend left] node[above]{e1}  (V4);
\draw (V3) to [bend right] node[below]{e2} (V4);
\draw (V3) -- node[left]{e3} (V2);
\draw (V2) -- node[below]{e5} (V1);
\draw (V2) arc (45:360+45:4mm) node[below left,xshift=-14pt,yshift=-14pt] {e4};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some advice:

1. read the tutorials in [the TikZ & PGF Manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), in particular, Section 5
2. read our [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) (the red words are a link, please click on it!)
3. put a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried, not only a snippet of an answer to one previous question of yours
4. [accept the answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) that solves your problem, you have many answers to your previous questions but you haven't accepted any.

Comment: thank you very much,  im happy to registrar  in stack exchange

Comment: @MaryamFasfous You're welcome! The best way to thank people here is by accepting the answer clicking on the check mark you find on the top left of the question (please do it also for your previous questions)!

Comment: @MaryamFasfous I think you accepted the wrong answer.